# Strict permission on files created in terminal script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, sudo

My script is creating a folder with files in it using

```
mkdir easy
echo aaa > easy/key_file
echo read_file_a_text > easy/read_file_a
cat > easy/write_file_a
....
```

for some reason, the files are created with a lock on them and i cannot delete them manually, only through terminal with sudo permissions. how do i create them normally?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the script with a sudo? If so, any and everything it creates will be owned by root because sudo means "execute code as the root user".

See here: https://superuser.com/questions/161702/why-is-my-sudo-generated-file-owned-by-root

Answer (score 0):

Check who is owner of this files. You can type ls -la and post here.